# Kubernetes Minikube: how to make Grafana instance visible to Intranet?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, grafana, minikube

I am working on a demo project using InfluxDB, Telegraf and Grafana running in a Kubernetes minikube under my local Linux user. I do not have root or sudo rights in the machine. I set up everything such that the minikube is running fine and I can see the exposed Grafana-service in a Webbrowser running on my local machine (url `http://<mini pod IP>:3000`).

Now I would like to make this service available to the outside world, so Grafana can be accessed by my colleagues. I played around with ingress, but got stuck as my PC is not registered at our company’s DNS-server, so I guess I do not have the option to use a host URL with the ingress, but have to use the ip of my PC such that the requests to the Grafana service from the outside world (company domain, not internet) look like `http://<pc IP address>:3000`

Is this possible? I am Fine with a Kubernetes solution or with proxy configurations for my local user, or another solution running under local user.

Comment: https://ngrok.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the service type from ClusterIP to NodePort, then you can access the service using your host/PC ip.

```
kubectl edit svc/grafana-service 

or

kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 pod/<grafana pod name> 3000:3000 &
```